# Google App Engine: ошибка Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine

При использовании HTTP-запросов из *Python* фреймворка *Google App Engine* иногда возникает ошибка:

> HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: ...`.

Как можно продлить время ожидания запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Что происходит:** Когда делается внешний HTTP-запрос в *Google App Engine*, фреймворк обращается к сервису *URLFetch*. Там создаётся ошибка `DeadlineExceededError`, затем GAE-клиент на Питоне её перехватывает и взамен бросает `HTTPException`.

**Решение:** *URLFetch* имеет имеет свою логику дедлайнов, которой можно управлять. Стандартный дедлайн равняется 5 секундам, этого бывает мало для некоторых запросов. Что делать:

```
# подключить нужный модуль
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

# поставить новый дедлайн (в секундах)
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(20)
```

**Нюансы:**

- Дедлайн устанавливается только для потока, исполняющегося в данный момент, поэтому устанавливать максимальное время ожидания нужно для каждого потока исполнения отдельно.
- Стоит учесть, что максимальное время ожидания составляет 60 секунд, и даже если поставить дедлайн больше этого, запросы, длящиеся более минуты, вызовут *DeadlineExceededError*.

**Полезные ссылки на GAE документацию:**

- [Документация URLFetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests)
- [Dealing with DeadlineExceededErrors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors)

<sub>Перевод и улучшение ответа: [HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698687/)</sub>